Value of input.step on illegal value for step attribute
Consider this code


const input = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
console.log(input.step); // Outputs: "foo" in Chrome/Safari/Firefox
console.log(input.getAttribute("step")); // Outputs: "foo" in all these three too
<input type="number" step="foo">



I can understand why getAttribute returns foo since that's expected as there's no validation performed but why does input.step yield foo. The spec reads so (emphasis mine)

if the rules for parsing floating-point number values, when they are
applied to the attribute's value, return an error, zero, or a number
less than zero, then the allowed value step is the default step
multiplied by the step scale factor.

and the default step is 1. So why do all the major browsers deviate from the standard? Am I reading the spec wrong or is there some other reason to this behavior? MDN docs too seem to indicate that the value of step property should be

It can be the string any or a positive floating point number.


It is using the default step. If you click the arrows in the input, it will round to an integer and step it by 1.

Your assumption is that the step property returns the allowed value step.

@Barmar Isn't that a correct assumption? MDN docs for step too say that It can be the string any or a positive floating point number.

My point is that input.step just returns what you put there. If it's invalid, the default is used for the actual stepping.

"A string that represents the element's step attribute". So the property is the same as the attribute.

Hmm..that's confusing to me. In the very next sentence it mentions, that It can be the string any or a positive floating point number.. foo is neither of those.

That's why this is an invalid value, because it doesn't meet that criteria. And as explained in the whatwg excerpt, the value is ignored and the default is used.

Your mistake is that you're expecting that reading the property will return the step that's being used, rather than the value in the attribute.

I begin to see what you are driving at and where I am erring. Since foo is neither of those, it uses the default step value (MDN is silent on invalid values). So then the question would be, how can I get the actual step value being used by the control? Is that even possible?

I suspect it isn't possible.
